# Generate .csv file programmatically from birt template

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, birt

I have generated a birt report template with follwoing steps:

1. Create Report Project in Eclispe
2. Create a report in Report Project
3. Create a data source using "JDBC Database connection for query builder" and provided details for my Postgres sql driver
4. Create a data set and provided the database query with its parameters
5. Create report parameters and map them to query parameters
6. Finally,run the report and generate the template.

What I want now is to keep this template in my current web project, bind the list of data to it and generate a csv file.

The birt report template is in xml format.